# UDP communication with XBee Wi-Fi S6B

Tags: sensors, wifi, hardware, wireless, zigbee

I am an absolute newbie when coming to using these modules. I am trying to setup a basic UDP connection between my XBee S6B (UDP Client) to my computer (UDP Server). I have added my codes below. The XBee program (UDP client) is a small modification of the [xbee python library](https://xbplib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started_with_xbee_python_library.html) on git made by Digi.

Note: Both devices (the xbee and computer are connected to the same wifi router).

UDP Server (computer)

```
import socket 

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 20001

sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((HOST,PORT))

while True:
    recv = sock.recv(1024)
    print(f"message: {recv[0]}\tIP: {recv[1]}")
```

UDP Client (XBee)

```
from digi.xbee import xsocket
from digi.xbee.devices import CellularDevice
from digi.xbee.models.protocol import IPProtocol

# TODO: Replace with the serial port where your local module is connected to.
PORT = "COM22"
# TODO: Replace with the baud rate of your local module.
BAUD_RATE = 115200
LISTEN_PORT = hex(5007)
ECHO_SERVER_ADDRESS = "192.168.0.131"
ECHO_SERVER_PORT = 20001
# TODO: Optionally, replace with the text to be sent to the server.
ECHO_SERVER_REQUEST = "May the force be with you"


def main():
    print(" +-----------------------------------------------------+")
    print(" | XBee Python Library Socket UDP Server Client Sample |")
    print(" +-----------------------------------------------------+\n")

    device = CellularDevice(PORT, BAUD_RATE)

    try:
        device.open()

        with xsocket.socket(device, IPProtocol.UDP) as sock:
            print("- Starting UDP server at port %s" % LISTEN_PORT)
            sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", LISTEN_PORT))
            print("- Sending '%s' to the echo server" % ECHO_SERVER_REQUEST)
            sock.sendto(ECHO_SERVER_REQUEST.encode("utf-8"), (ECHO_SERVER_ADDRESS, ECHO_SERVER_PORT))
            print("- Waiting for incoming data")
            answer, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
            if answer is not None:
                print("- Data received from %s:%s - '%s'" % (address[0], address[1], answer.decode("utf-8")))
    finally:
        if device is not None and device.is_open():
            device.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am having difficulty understanding how to fix the errors I am facing. I know I have to change something on XCTU but I am unsure what. I have already set AP = 1 which means its in API mode.

```
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\digi\xbee\devices.py", line 449, in _check_at_cmd_response_is_valid
    raise ATCommandException(message=response.status.description,
digi.xbee.exception.ATCommandException: Invalid command
```

Any suggestion on this would be highly appreciated!